# jQuery select child with class only not all

Tags: jquery

I want to show some images when i hover on others. So far i have tried this:

```
$('.image').hover(function() {
    $('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});
```

But i dont want to show all images when i hover on one image.

I have this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PNRwk/)

Now i want when i hover to an image with class `.image`, to change `opacity` only in the image with class `.icon` that is clild of the one i hover, not all.

I hover the first image only up image changes `opacity`, not both. I hover the second image, only down image change `opacity`

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that i want the image that is showing up to stay when i hover over it. Actually the two images are one inside each other. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PNRwk/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.siblings()` this way:

```
$('.image, .icon').hover(function(e) {
   if(e.type === 'mouseenter' && $(e.target).is('.image')){
      $('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
      $(this).siblings('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
   }
   if(e.type === 'mouseleave' && $(e.target).is('.icon')){
      $('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 0});   
   }
});
```

and change your context to current selector with  `$(this)`

[**UPDATED Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNRwk/20/)

Comment: @laaposto oops its a late reply, you can try this updated code and fiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $(this).children('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNRwk/14/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery $(this) to indicate current class element and you can use parent().find('element or class or id name') to traverse the appropriate element

```
$('.image').hover(function() {
$(this).parent().find('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
$(this).parent().find('.icon').stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});
```